# Joomla: Add Positions to Blog Content area

Tags: joomla, position, blogs

I am trying to add new positions to the Content area of the sheet.
This is, I would like my blog entries to be like this:

Post #1
Post #2
Post #3
New Position #1
Post #4
Post #5
Post #6
New Position #2
Post #7
Post #8
post #9

Eventually those two new positions will be used for banner adverts.

I don't want to insert positions into articles, because the blog will be very dynamic and articles will scroll down quickly. Besides, anything that can be automated, should.
I have been advised that the clever way to do this is to create a Blog Layout override.
Now, considering that I am a newbie, am flying blind with one hand tied to my nose and my cat as a co-pilot, I am starting to feel a tad lost.
I did read everything I could about PHP and overrides but it does not seem to be enough.
I am using Artisteer to create the template, which is *extremely* basic, no fancy stuff of any kind, just basic styling. The template I am using is called "testa4_50" (yeah... I am on version 50 of the sucker... steep learning curve... don't get me started....).
I am using Xampp on a Windoze XP as localhost for testing purposes.
My Joomla implementation is 3.0.3
Artisteer seems to make abundant use of overrides, so I thought it should not be that hard to do... big mistake....

The first thing I tried, is to see if I could insert a new position somewhere in the body of the home page to try to understand the code.

Steps I took:

1 - Locate templateDetails.xml in C:\xampp\htdocs\j303b1\templates\testa4_50\
2 - Locate the  list and add my "position-new"; that looked like:

```
<positions>
        <position>debug</position>
        <position>position-2</position>
        <position>position-4</position>
        <position>position-5</position>
        <position>position-7</position>
        <position>position-9</position>
        <position>position-10</position>
        <position>position-11</position>
        <position>position-12</position>
        <position>position-15</position>
        <position>position-16</position>
        <position>position-17</position>
        <position>position-18</position>
        <position>position-19</position>
        <position>position-20</position>
        <position>position-21</position>
        <position>position-22</position>
        <position>position-23</position>
        <position>position-24</position>
        <position>position-25</position>
        <position>position-26</position>
        <position>position-27</position>
        <position>position-new</position>
    </positions>
```

3 - Locate index.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\j303b1\templates\testa4_50\
4 - Find the correct spot in the positions block:

```
<?php
  echo $view->position('position-19', 'art-nostyle');
  if ($view->containsModules('position-2'))
    echo artxPost($view->position('position-2'));
  echo $view->positions(array('position-20' => 50, 'position-21' => 50), 'art-article');
  echo $view->position('position-12', 'art-nostyle');
  echo artxPost(array('content' => '<jdoc:include type="message" />', 'classes' => ' art-messages'));
  echo '<jdoc:include type="component" />';
  echo $view->position('position-22', 'art-nostyle');
  echo $view->positions(array('position-23' => 50, 'position-24' => 50), 'art-article');
  echo $view->position('position-25', 'art-nostyle');
?>
```

5 - Add my new position copying the existing code:

```
<?php
  echo $view->position('position-19', 'art-nostyle');
  if ($view->containsModules('position-2'))
    echo artxPost($view->position('position-2'));
  echo $view->positions(array('position-20' => 50, 'position-21' => 50), 'art-article');
  echo $view->position('position-12', 'art-nostyle');
  echo $view->position('position-new', 'art-nostyle');
  echo artxPost(array('content' => '<jdoc:include type="message" />', 'classes' => ' art-messages'));
  echo '<jdoc:include type="component" />';
  echo $view->position('position-22', 'art-nostyle');
  echo $view->positions(array('position-23' => 50, 'position-24' => 50), 'art-article');
  echo $view->position('position-25', 'art-nostyle');
?>
```

6 - Check positions in Joomla / Preview
7 - It all works OK.

So, I figure out the code  "echo $view->position('position-new', 'art-nostyle');" should work anywhere else too.

Now, I tried to create a new position anywhere in the blog.

Steps I took:

1 - Locate blog.php in \Dell-pc\xampp\htdocs\J303b1\templates\testa4_50\html\com_content\category (the complete file is attached to this post)

2 - Find the correct spot in the file

```
echo artxPost(array('header-text' => $view->pageHeading, 'content' => ob_get_clean()));

?>
<?php $leadingcount=0 ; ?>
<?php if (!empty($this->lead_items)) : ?>
<div class="items-leading">
    <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
        <div class="leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>">
            <?php
                $this->item = &$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php $leadingcount++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

3 - Insert the code:

```
echo artxPost(array('header-text' => $view->pageHeading, 'content' => ob_get_clean()));

?>
<?php echo $view->position('position-new', 'art-nostyle') ?>
<?php $leadingcount=0 ; ?>
<?php if (!empty($this->lead_items)) : ?>
<div class="items-leading">
    <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
        <div class="leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>">
            <?php
                $this->item = &$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                echo $view->position('position-new', 'art-nostyle');
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php $leadingcount++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

4 - Test = FAIL (the position does not appear anywhere in the home page)

5 - Chage the code to

> 

and insert in the same position. Test = FAIL.

============================
At this point, I am stumped. I can't insert a new position anywhere in the content area.
Originaly I thought of inserting this code in the loop above (to see if I could insert at least one new position after the third Post):

```
<?php $leadingcount=0 ; ?>
<?php if (!empty($this->lead_items)) : ?>
<div class="items-leading">
    <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
        <div class="leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>">
            <?php
                $this->item = &$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                echo $view->position('position-new', 'art-nostyle');
                If ($leadingcount==3) echo $view->position('position-new', 'art-nostyle');
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php $leadingcount++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But of course, it does not work.

Any suggestions / advice will be greately appreciated indeed!

Blog.php File

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';

if ('artisteer' == JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params->get('blogLayoutType')) {
    require 'art_blog.php';
    return;
}

Artx::load("Artx_Content");

$view = new ArtxContent($this, $this->params);

echo $view->beginPageContainer('blog');
ob_start();
if ($this->params->get('show_category_title', 1) || strlen($this->params->get('page_subheading'))) {
    echo '<h2>';
    echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_subheading'));
    if ($this->params->get('show_category_title') && strlen($this->category->title))
        echo '<span class="subheading-category">' . $this->category->title . '</span>';
    echo '</h2>';
}

if ($this->params->def('show_description', 1) || $this->params->def('show_description_image', 1)) {
    echo '<div class="category-desc">';
    if ($this->params->get('show_description_image') && $this->category->getParams()->get('image'))
        echo '<img src="' . $this->category->getParams()->get('image') . '" alt="" />';
    if ($this->params->get('show_description') && $this->category->description)
        echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $this->category->description, '', 'com_content.category');
    echo '</div>';
}
echo artxPost(array('header-text' => $view->pageHeading, 'content' => ob_get_clean()));

?>
<?php echo $view->position('position-new', 'xhtml') ?>
<?php $leadingcount=0 ; ?>
<?php if (!empty($this->lead_items)) : ?>
<div class="items-leading">
    <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
        <div class="leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>">
            <?php
                $this->item = &$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                echo $view->position('position-new', 'art-nostyle');
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php $leadingcount++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
    $introcount = (count($this->intro_items));
    $counter = 0;
?>
<?php if (!empty($this->intro_items)) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : ?>
    <?php
        $key= ($key-$leadingcount)+1;
        $rowcount=( ((int)$key-1) % (int) $this->columns) +1;
        $row = $counter / $this->columns ;
        if ($rowcount==1) : ?>
            <div class="items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns;?> <?php echo 'row-'.$row ; ?>">
       <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="item column-<?php echo $rowcount;?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>">
    <?php
        $this->item = &$item;
        echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
    ?>
    </div>
        <?php $counter++; ?>
        <?php if (($rowcount == $this->columns) or ($counter ==$introcount)): ?>
    <span class="row-separator"></span>
</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
if (!empty($this->link_items)) {
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="items-more">' . $this->loadTemplate('links') . '</div>';
    echo artxPost(ob_get_clean());
}
?>
<?php if (!empty($this->children[$this->category->id])&& $this->maxLevel != 0) : ?>
    <?php ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="cat-children">
        <h3><?php echo JTEXT::_('JGLOBAL_SUBCATEGORIES'); ?></h3>
        <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('children'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo artxPost(ob_get_clean()); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php

if (($this->params->def('show_pagination', 1) == 1 || $this->params->get('show_pagination') == 2)
    && $this->pagination->get('pages.total') > 1)
{
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="pagination">';
    if ($this->params->def('show_pagination_results', 1))
        echo '<p class="counter">' . $this->pagination->getPagesCounter() . '</p>';
    echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks();
    echo '</div>';
    echo ob_get_clean();
}

echo $view->endPageContainer();
```

Comment: it's not so hard actually, are you really sure you're invoking the right files? try to output some debug <h1> (those should be easy to see) so you're sure that's the right file, I do the same and it was fairly straightforward to achieve (although I have fixed content, yours is dynamic (a position), but for that you have the loadposition plugin to copy from.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work for me in Joomla 1.5 and could be used anywhere. I wouldn't bother copying anything that artisteer tries to do, just import the helper and get the modules.

```
/***************************************
* Load module in a view file*/

// import the module helper
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
// this is where you want to load your module position
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('moduleposition');
foreach($modules as $module)
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

For joomla 3 I think it would be more like this

```
/***************************************
* Load module in a view file*/

// import the module helper
$document   = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('module');
// this is where you want to load your module position
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('moduleposition');
foreach($modules as $module)
{
echo $renderer->render($module);
}
```